# XSD anytype and JAXB

Tags: xsd, jaxb

I have an xsd definition (from www.tmforum.org ossj common api v1.5)

```
<element name="primaryKey" nillable="false">
   <complexType mixed="false">                   
      <complexContent mixed="false">
         <extension base="anyType"/>                   
      </complexContent>
   </complexType>
</element>
```

and would like to generate an xml as follows

```
<ossj-co-v1-5:primaryKey>mykey</ossj-co-v1-5:primaryKey>
```

The PrimaryKey class generated from the xsd using xjc requires a DOM Element to be stored in a list (see the generated PrimaryKey class at the bottom". "myKey" here is a TextNode and since its not an DOM Element, it cannot be added to xjc generated PrimaryKey class. How should I proceed to get the required output?

Here is the PrimaryKey class generated from the xsd

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "any"
    })
public static class PrimaryKey {

    @XmlAnyElement
    protected List<Element> any;
    @XmlAnyAttribute
    private Map<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<QName, String>();

    public List<Element> getAny() {
        if (any == null) {
            any = new ArrayList<Element>();
        }
        return this.any;
    }


    public Map<QName, String> getOtherAttributes() {
        return otherAttributes;
    }

}
```

Comment: What type of property values do you need the any property to hold, and are you ok with solutions that involve manually modifying the generated model?

Comment: It should just hold a string value. I dont want to manually modify the generated classes as they are compile time generated. Extending the generated classes or using xjb bindings should be fine. But I am looking for examples.

Answer (score 3):

The following object models would work for your scenario.  I'll try to dig up the approprate schema customizations to produce these object models.

**Option #1**

You could have your code look like the following.  This would mean that the element "primaryKey" would cause the object PrimaryKey to be instantiated with the corresponding text content being set on the any property.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) 
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"any" }) 
public static class PrimaryKey { 

    @XmlValue
    protected String any; 

    @XmlAnyAttribute 
    private Map<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<QName, String>(); 

    public List<Element> getAny() { 
        if (any == null) { 
            any = new ArrayList<Element>(); 
        } 
        return this.any; 
    } 


    public Map<QName, String> getOtherAttributes() { 
        return otherAttributes; 
    } 

}
```

**Option #2**

If you want an outer object to have a String property corresponding to the primaryKey you could do the following:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) 
public class Root {

    // @XmlElement is implied
    private String primaryKey;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Option#1 getAny() cannot return String as the signature returns List.

The **Option#2 indeed works**. Thanks!

Here is how my OSSJ code modification looks:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ManagedEntityKey", propOrder = {
    "applicationContext",
    "applicationDN",
    "type",
    "primaryKey"
})
public class ManagedEntityKey {
   @XmlElement(required = true)
   protected String primaryKey;
   //protected ManagedEntityKey.PrimaryKey primaryKey;
```

And ofcourse the signature of the setters and getters should be modified.

Comment: Did this end up fully working for you?  I'm running into the same issue however when I do like you did - even doing the setters and getters - it now breaks things - yes, I can get a primary key tag's value but the "type" attribute is now gone