# JAXB Accessing String content from anyType

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I have a predefined xsd schema (which I cannot modify unfortunately) for which I like to generate corresponding JAVA classes via JAXB. Currently I'm struggling with a complex type which is defined as follows.

```
  <xsd:complexType name="AttributeType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="xsd:anyType">
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:anyURI" use="required"/>
        <xsd:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

The XML examples provided, allow direct string content, like this:

```
<attribute id="myValue">201</attribute>
```

as well as embedded xml like this:

```
<attribute id="address">
    <example:Address xmlns:example="http://example.com/ns">
        <Street>100 Nowhere Street</Street>
        <City>Fancy</City>
        <State>DC</State>
        <Zip>99999</Zip>
    </example:Address>
</attribute>
```

When running the xjc process without further binding modification, I get a class like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AttributeType", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
public class AttributeType {

    @XmlAnyElement
    protected List<Element> any;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anyURI")
    protected String id;
    @XmlAnyAttribute
    private Map<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<QName, String>();

    // getter setter omitted
}
```

The problem with this is, that I am not able to get the string content of the first example. This might reference to [XSD anytype and JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488141/xsd-anytype-and-jaxb), but actually I don't know to achieve this without modifying the XSD. Thus how can I get the string content? Btw. I'm using the maven cxf-codegen-plugin for generating the source.

Comment: Were you able to get the problem worked out?  The referenced link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488141/xsd-anytype-and-jaxb) is the exact same problem I have and I'm trying to figure out how to overcome it.  The answers there didnt work out.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem come from the fact that the generated mapping looks for child element, but not text.

If you could modify your XSD, the solution would be :

```
<xsd:complexType name="AttributeType">
    <xsd:complexContent mixed="true">
      <xsd:extension base="xsd:anyType">
       <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:anyURI" use="required"/>
       <xsd:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

But since you can't ...

If you can afford to modify your source code, change :

```
@XmlAnyElement
protected List<Element> any;
```

To

```
@XmlAnyElement
@XmlMixed
protected List<Object> any;
```

The Object list should contain `Element` for child element and `String` for text.

Comment: Changing the generated source is also not the best solution here, since the XSDs are "frequently" updated and thus generated in the build process. Is there a way to accomplish this modification maybe via binding customizations?